# Today's time in time tag

Tags: time, html

For date ranges, I currently use this format (until precise specifications come up):

```
<time datetime="2012-11">November 2012</time> - <time datetime="2013-01">January 2013</time>
```

I was wondering if there is, or will be, a way to indicate today's date. I mean, I know we can do this:

```
<time datetime="2013-03-05">Today</time>
```

but I would like to have something like this:

```
<time datetime="now">Today</time>
```

If not, I plan to leave the "Today" word with no extra markup. Would you recommend a better solution?

Thanks!

---

EDIT: To add bit of context, I am building an online resume, hence the date ranges as well as the ones that involve: `<time datetime="yyyy-mm">[Month] [Year]</time> - Present`.

Comment: I don't think there can be a valid technical answer to this — there's no definite practical or technical requirement, the concept is vague and the related specs fall short of anything useful. Personally, I believe the `<time>` element is [a bit of a mistake](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/04/making_time_saf.html). If there are no practical implications, it makes little difference what you do. Besides, on a purely pointless semantics level, isn't 'today' a different concept to 'now'?

Comment: It's a bit hard to imagine where this would be useful. If you open the page today, leave it open and look at it again tomorrow, isn't "now" wrong? Without seeing the context, I can't really imagine a situation where "now" would be appropriate.

Comment: @Barney: Thanks for the comment. Even though it can surely be improved, I personally like the way things go, semantically speaking. And, OK, maybe I messed up a bit by writing both "Today" and "Now" Let's say "Present" then :-)

Comment: @Juhana: Thanks too. The situation I am encountering right now is a list of date ranges, the last range being "[Month] [Year] - Present". By "now" or "today", I meant that the range would still apply when reading (I am not seeking how to dinamically indicate a "now" moment, but rather specify the date on semantic level). But of course, it implies that any changes in the actual ranges (in real life) have to be properly updated on the website... but this is not the same problem, I think :-)

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I had the impression that `<time>` is to make easier for machines to semantically parse a document, so using a non-standard format would probably not help there.

Comment: I do understand what you want to do, however, right now it's a dead-end reflexion as [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/time.html#time.attrs.datetime) does not specify such a way to semantically indicate such a relative time. IMHO, there is no point creating "custom" nonstandard markup. I think in the absence of a better solution, I'd generate the date via a server-side language to current day. It's not semantically "today", but it's accurate.

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande: I didn't plan to use a "custom" nonstandard markup ;-) I was merely asking if there is a better way than leaving "Present" with no markup at all, but I will leave it like that until a better solution comes up. However, the server-side generated date does not do the job, as "X - 2013-03-05" would mean "this has ended today" while (assuming 2013-03-05 is today) "X - Present" means "this is still going". Anyway, I just wondered if I had missed something in the official specs, now I know I don't, thanks everyone.

Comment: I like when I get downvotes with no comment from the downvoter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your efforts.

Just to clarify things, I was not looking for ways to dynamically update the content of the datetime attribute. I just wanted to know if there was a way to semantically indicate the "present" day or time.

The answer is: **no, there is no way to do that**.

I do believe that there might be a change someday. Some of you wondered when this could be useful. I agree that currently there is no need for that, but [there might be ways to indicate date ranges in the future specs](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Time_element) (the `<time>` element is still in draft, after all). If so, there could be ranges that start at a precise point and that are still going, giving a use case for a "present"/"now"/... keyword, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Try using php or JavaScript to get the local time from the user's computer, then output that as text.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php for instructions on doing it with php.

EDIT:  It gets the server time, not the user's time.  To get the user's time, you have to use javascript.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not looking for a technical (and a bit hackish, for that matter) way to achieve what is not specified by the specs. See my own answer for more info :-)

Answer (score 0):

surfing the web i found this question, i thought it would be cool to answer since today we have an answer to that.

```
<time datetime="P4DT4H3M">four days, and three minutes</time>
```

To better understand you can see here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time

Comment: It's nice to be able to represent a duration for sure, but unfortunately this does not answer the question, which was to represent today or now in the semantic markup.

Comment: @astorije You’re right, I just wanted to leave a reference for a very similar question for those who arrive here like me