# How can I semantically define within the <time> tag 'the present'

Tags: date, time, microformats, html

I am using ***time*** tag to define a time—seemed like the right approach ;-)

My problem however is the value I want to place within the ***time*** tag is NOW: *the present*. I get this validation error:

```
The text content of element time was not in the required format:
The literal did not satisfy the time-datetime format."
```

Looking at the spec, it doesn't seem possible to define *'NOW'*. That's a nuisance. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: Good question; the use case context is a resume listing of projects and experience. But I want it all to be machine readable as well.

Comment: Duplicate of [Today's time in time tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223317/todays-time-in-time-tag)
 (shameless plug: my own question :) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. The [`time` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) in HTML5 is defined as markup for specific moments or periods or durations of time or for time offsets, not for all concepts related to time.

You can write e.g. `<time datetime="2013-04-06T13:53">now</time>`, thereby associating a fixed moment of time with the text content “now”. I don’t see how this could be useful, and the usefulness of the `time` element in general is questionable (it looks like markup for markup’s sake), but things like this are all you can do to “define ‘NOW’” with `time`.

Comment: I think it can be very useful, e.g. here on Stack Overflow it says for this answer "answered 4 hours ago". Now "4 hours ago" could be marked up with the `time` element, containing the publishing time. If someone archives the page, such relative time references aren't useful, but thanks to `time` the date can be included in a formal way.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this markup for now:

```
<time datetime="2013">Present</time>
```

No more errors, and it's symatic. It's just a shame there is no accepted variable for NOW.